# Representação little endian do menor para o maior em uma CPU Intel?

Tags: c

Sobre endianess do meu PC Intel, ocorre o seguinte:

```
int i = 0X23456789;
unsigned char* a = (char*)&i;

for(int i = 0;i < 4;++i)
{
   printf("%.2X\n",a[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
89
67
45
23
```

Porém:

```
int i = 0X23456789;
unsigned char* a = (char*)&i;
printf("%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X",*a,*a++,*a++,*a++);
```

Output:

```
23
45
67
89
```

Qual a razão do `printf` se comportar de diferentes maneiras nas duas situações acima?

Comment: A dúvida é boa, mas para entender seu raciocínio e elaborar em cima, como concluiu que a questão é realmente de endianness? Já considerou outras possibilidades?

Comment: Os dois são iguais, o problema é a ordem dos parametros. O ultimo `&a++` será executado antes do terceiro, antes do segundo e então o primeiro `*a`.  Quebre isso em vários `printf`, como `    printf("%.2X\n",*a++);    printf("%.2X\n",*a++);    printf("%.2X\n",*a++);    printf("%.2X\n",*a);` e vai ver que o resultado é igual ao do `for`.

Comment: @Bacco estou começando a estudar endianess, só queria saber na prática como identificar a ordem em que os bytes são lidos e escritos em minha máquina.

Comment: Robson sim, levantei o questionamento como uma forma de adiantar o assunto, e fazer uma provocação a pensar (não só para você, mas para quem fosse responder já que eu não estava com tempo de elaborar mais), isso foi antes de ter a resposta do colega @Inkeliz que vai direto ao problema de fato. Sobre endianness, a melhor coisa que faz de fato é ler direto da memória individualmente se um dia precisar determinar (mas isso só como experiência, normalmente os próprios compiladores já tem algum built-in ou define para te informar isso, se um dia precisar de um código condicional multiplataforma).

Comment: @Bacco endianess sempre vai fazer diferença porque os bytes serão apresentados em outra ordem, ainda que se use por exemplo o mesmo gcc e as mesmas opções, mudando de arquitetura.

Comment: O loop vai receber os valores em outra ordem, para o mesmo código, @Inkeliz não considerou isso ao escrever, indo "direto ao problema de fato"

Comment: Acho que a pergunta misturou dois assuntos: *endianess* e ordem em que os argumentos são avaliados. Se a questão era sobre o *endianess*, deveria ter como [mcve] só o primeiro código dando resultados diferentes em máquinas diferentes, por exemplo. Se a questão era a ordem, poderia trocar para algo como o sugerido abaixo (`int i = 0; printf("%d, %d", i, i++);`). Da forma que está, um acaba sendo ruído pro outro, tanto que cada resposta escolheu focar em um deles. Minha sugestão seria separar em duas perguntas, assim o site fica mais organizado...

Comment: ... Lembrando que o objetivo do site é ser uma base de conhecimento sobre programação, com perguntas **objetivas e focadas** em um único assunto. Misturar 2 assuntos distintos vai contra esse objetivo

Comment: O comportamento dos dois códigos do autor não tem relação com endianness (a palavra está lá só por uma conclusão inicial do autor que já foi "desmistificada"). Seja qual for a plataforma, o loop e o printf avulso (feitos na mesma ordem sequencial) darão o mesmo output. Obviamente que o output vai ser diferente comparando duas plataformas distintas, mas isso não foi a causa do fenômeno observado, até porque o autor disse qual era o target no título, e rodou os dois testes na plataforma especificada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X",*a,*a++,*a++,*a++);
```

Essa chamada a `printf()` tem um comportamento indefinido --- UB. Não há garantia sobre a ordem da avaliação dos incrementos `++` e dos ponteiros resultantes. Veja o código gerado usando a opção de seu compilador. `-S` no caso do gcc, `/Fa` no MSVC.

Evite esse tipo de construção a todo custo.

No fundo qualquer operação dentro da lista de argumentos de uma função é um risco porque você pode remover  a chamada e esquecer de repor a operação. Ou copiar a chamada e fazer mais vezes a mesma coisa...

Cada `*a++` vai ter o resultado esperado: o valor apontado por `a`. E depois o ponteiro `a` avança `sizeof(*a)`.  Só que hora de chamar `printf()` a ordem em que isso é avaliado não é definida pela norma e pode acontecer qualquer coisa porque tem 3 na mesma lista de argumentos. Vai avaliar da direita para a esquerda? Ou da esquerda para a direita? E se o valor de `*a` for calculado antes e usado 3x para otimizar, e o ponteiro incrementado 3X de modo independente? `printf()` não vai ver esses resultados e vai mostrar 3x o mesmo valor. Mas na linha seguinte estará tudo certo.

E um mesmo compilador rodando em uma arquitetura *Big Endian* vai pegar os valores na memória em uma ordem e em outra em uma arquitetura *Little Endian* levando a resultados diferentes. Isso --- *endianess* --- é bem definido, mas somado ao descrito acima leva a mais confusão.

### Endianess e um EXEMPLO em C

Um modo comum de testar se a máquina em que o programa está rodando usa *Big-Endian* ou *Little-Endian* é considerar um int valendo 1 e ver se o primeiro byte vale 1. O clássico

```
int little_endian()
{ 
    int um = 1; 
    // redefine &um como char* para ver se
    // o primeiro byte vale 1
    return *((char*)(&um)) == 1;
}
```

O programa abaixo mostra os valores para um int de 32 bits com um único byte 1 e os outros 0. Usa uma union para mostrar os valores como estão na memória e serve para ilustrar isso. E chama a tal função do exemplo acima.

#### saída do exemplo

```
    ==> Valor do int (32bits): 1

        Bytes 0/1/2/3: 0x01 0x00  0x00 0x00


    ==> Valor do int (32bits): 256

        Bytes 0/1/2/3: 0x00 0x01  0x00 0x00


    ==> Valor do int (32bits): 65536

        Bytes 0/1/2/3: 0x00 0x00  0x01 0x00


    ==> Valor do int (32bits): 16777216

        Bytes 0/1/2/3: 0x00 0x00  0x00 0x01


        Little Endian? SIM
```

#### o código do exemplo

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int little_endian();

int main(void)
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t d_word;
        uint8_t  byte[4];
    }   teste;

    int val[4] = {1, 256, 65536, 16777216};

    for (int n=0; n < sizeof(val) / sizeof(val[0]); n += 1)
    {
        teste.d_word = val[n];
        printf("\n\n\
    ==> Valor do int (32bits): %d\n\n\
        Bytes 0/1/2/3: 0x%02X 0x%02X  0x%02X 0x%02X\n",
        teste.d_word, teste.byte[0], teste.byte[1],
        teste.byte[2], teste.byte[3]);
    }

    const char* sn[2] = {"NAO","SIM"};
    printf("\n\n\tLittle Endian? %s\n", sn[little_endian()]);

    return 0;
}

int little_endian()
{ 
    int um = 1; 
    // redefine &um como char para ver se o primeiro byte
    // vale 1
    return *((char*)(&um)) == 1;
}

// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/555733/representa
//%c3%a7%c3%a3o-litle-endian-do-menor-para-o-maior-em-uma-
//  cpu-intel
```

Comment: Então minha resposta, que explica a razão do problema e tem um programa em C com a saída acompanhando não é útil? **Preciso melhorar, está claro**

Comment: Dois votos como inútil hoje. Pena que não se deram oa trabalho de explicar como eu poderia tornar a resposta melhor. Nada como o anonimato

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Sim, o printf que escrevi tem como resultado um comportamento indefinido, e eu devo evitar tal prática de programação. Essa foi sua contribuição e te agreço por isso;não farei mais tal coisa. Porém, além do que tu escreveu Inkeliz demonstrou que o output do meu código não tem nada a ver com endianess, mas como cada compilador determina a ordem de operação do printf que escrevi. Como percebi que não entendo de endianess, não comentarei sobre o programa em C que disponibilizou. Mas, aqui fica meu muito obrigado a todas respostas.

Comment: Esse é o início de minha responsta, @Robson _"Essa chamada a printf() tem um comportamento indefinido --- UB. Não há garantia sobre a ordem da avaliação dos incrementos e dos ponteiros"_  O exemplo que te mostrei indica como você poderia ter feito em seu programa para verificar isso.

Comment: E imagino que tenha entendido que se rodar numa máquina Big Endian com o mesmo compilador o resultado vai ser diferente então sua afirmação e a da resposta que citou não procedem: tem também a ver com litttle/big endian a saída. O programa deveria servir para você entender essa questão de ordem do byte mais significativo e se eu não consegui preciso mudar algo lá. Notou os 4 int com 1 byte 1 e os outros 0 ?

Comment: Realmente fiquei com essa compreensão. Se é o compilador que determina a forma de se ler os bytes com printf, então é um problemão!!! Realmente, a sua resposta além de demonstrar que é uma má prática a forma como eu tratei a ordem de avaliação dos incrementos, ainda me trouxe um código que possibilita o que quero - que é descobrir o endianess da minha máquina. Esclarecendo o endianess da minha máquina consigo entender porque lendo sob matriz tenho uma ordem, e lendo sob ponteiros tenho outra ordem.

Comment: oh... o que o compilador é livre para determinar é a ordem de avaliação de coisas como os  operadores ++ dentro da lista de argumentos do printf(). O endianess é determinado pela arquitetura e determina a ordem dos bytes dentro de uma word na memória, se começa a carga pelo primeiro ou pelo segundo byte e por isso escrevi o programa para mostrar o byte `0x01` _"navegando"_ na DWORD.

Answer (score 5):

O problema não tem relação com o *endianness*, e sim com a ordem das operações na função.

Para visualizar melhor, troque para:

```
int i = 0X23456789;
unsigned char* a = (char*)&i;
printf("%.2X\n",*a++);
printf("%.2X\n",*a++);
printf("%.2X\n",*a++);
printf("%.2X\n",*a);
```

Isso resultará em:

```
89
67
45
23
```

Exatamente a mesma ordem do `for`.

---

Então por que o seu `printf` dá outro resultado? Porque a ordem as operações importam e compilador também parece poder alterar. [Segundo a resposta do SO (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/376288/3043018), a ordem não é determinística, e cada compilador pode dar seus pulos.

```
printf("%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X",*a,*a++,*a++,*a++);
```

O que você acha é que feito primeiro? O que você quer é fazer: `*a` e depois `*a++`. Mas será que essa é a ordem que o compilador vai fazer? Recomendo que veja no https://godbolt.org/z/4P1aPKqKx. Pode passar o mouse por cima para ver melhor cada coisa e pode usar vários compiladores diferentes.

Alguns compiladores, como CLang e ICX, dão alguns warnings:

```
<source>:6:38: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
printf("%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X\n%.2X",*a,*a++,*a++,*a++);
                                 ~   ^
```

Se você compilar usando ICX (Intel Compiler), a ordem muda:

```
89
89
67
45
```

Já o compilador ICC, a ordem é diferente:

```
23
89
67
45
```

Compilando com Zig CC, a ordem também é igual ao do ICX:

```
89
89
67
45
```

Com o GCC, é a ordem que mencionou:

```
23
45
67
89
```

---

Mas, para simplicar, considere o seguinte código:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d, %d", i, i++);
    return 0;
}
```

O que você acha que é o resultado? `0, 1` ou `1, 0` ou `0, 0`? Então, isso depende do compilador, não do *endianness*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Me ajudou a perceber que preciso entender melhor endianess.

Comment: **Depende também de endianess...** O mesmo compilador numa plataforma BigEndian vai te dar um resultado diferente porque os bytes virão em outra ordem. Pense nisso

Comment: @arfneto mas a ordem dos dois casos (com o `for` ou com o `++`) serão iguais.

Comment: sim. o conteúdo é que será diferente.

Comment: O memso compilador, duas plataformas. Os bytes serão apresentados em outra ordem

Comment: Esse é ponto. Talvez eu pudesse deixar isso mais claro a resposta. O que quis dizer com "não tem relação com endiness" é o comportamento diferente entre o `for` e `++`, que é a pergunta principal: "Qual a razão do printf se comportar de diferentes maneiras nas duas situações acima?". O endianness terá relação com o CPU, isso é claro, mas os dois métodos terão o mesmo resultado entre si.

Answer (score -1):

Em uma arquitetura x86 (intel, amd...), o número 0X23456789 é armazenado assim: 89 67 34 23.

x86 é uma arquitetura chamada "little-endian": https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Ao usar uma notação de matriz, você lê os bytes na ordem da memória.
Você também pode ler este array como uma string:

```c
        union u_u {
            int i;
            unsigned char c[4];
        } u;
        u.i = 0X23456789;
        // Stored in memory on a x86 architecture like that : 89 67 34 23

        for(int i = 0;i < 4;++i) {
            printf("%.2X\n",u.c[i]);
        }
```

Quando você usa uma notação de ponteiro, você a lê como o processador, na ordem inversa: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Transfer%C3%AAncia_de_dados_entre_processador_e_mem%C3%B3ria

Comment: Nesse sentido, qual seria mais eficiente(ou não tem importância no que compreende otimização)?Lendo em notação de matriz há alguma perda em comparação a ler como o processador lê( iteração de ponteiros)?

Comment: Na minha opinião, acho que a notação de iteração de ponteiro é mais rápida, mas isso não deve ser muito. Eu prefiro a notação de índice. É mais legível. O uso de uma notação em vez de outra pode ser escolhido dependendo do que você deseja fazer com ela posteriormente.

Comment: obrigado pela opinião.